# Unable to install ADT in Eclipse 3.8

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse 3.8 and have also downloaded the SDK tools. Both separately. I ran the SDK manager. Everything got installed but it did not show in the eclipse. Later I tried installing the ADT explicitly. Everything went fine, I ran the SDK manager, installed whatever I needed but when I restarted the Eclipse, there was no sign of ADT ever installed. Please help.

Comment: what do you expect Eclipse to look like when you restart it after installing adt?

Comment: It opens up with a dialog box saying something like android development. I do not even the Window-> Android Manager. Even though under the tag of "already installed" i do see all the ADT tools beings installed but not even a single trace of android.

Comment: well then, how about making a new android project?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the SDK tools are not bound to eclipse and therefor don't change the eclipse installations. They are just a set of tools used to develop java applications for eclipse. What you need to install is the [eclipse adt plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) using the installation dialog from within eclipse (Help => Install new Software). You could also download the [pre-bundled eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) with an integrated adt plugin and sdk.

Comment: I don't know how you can answer an non-existent question

Comment: Just starting with stackoverflow. Maybe i should have just commented his post.

Comment: I did exactly the same. It installed all the ADT tools later it showed up the SDK manager, I selected the desired packages but when I restarted eclipse, all vanished.

Comment: Did you change the workspace? Maybe you installed the plugins into the workspace location.